# Delete nth row if the sum of columns b and c exceeds the nth value of column a

Tags: r

How can i delete all rows in which the sum of columns b and c exceeds the value of a.

For example : First row has column a value = 50.000 and column b value = 30.000 and column c value = 30.000 . Column b + c in first row = 60.000 which is greater than column a which value is 50.000 so i want to delete it. How can i do this in R?

I want to do this for all the rows in the dataset.

Comment: Probably `df[rowSums(df[, c("b", "c")]) <= df$c, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical condition by summing the columns 'b' and 'c', checking the output is less than or equal to 'a' and use that logical vector to subset the rows.

```
df[with(df, (b + c) <=  a),]
#   a  b  c
#2 70 20 30
```

NOTE: The results are based on the OP's description.  This is downvoted unnecessarily.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(50, 70), b = c(30, 20), c = c(30, 30))
```

Comment: I up vote it for no reason ! to hurt those that do not appreciate your time. Thanks. Here if you spend time to answer a question, good or bad, you spend your valuable time. I believe we should appreciate it . However, it is sometimes not very good. if you look at my votes, I give it to all others which show me something and I learn something from them. I personally appreciate your help

Comment: Thnks for yours answer!!! I can't upvote you yet . It won't let me. Btw why is my thread downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `filter` verb/function from `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(a=c(50,40),b=c(30,10),c=c(30,20))
#   a  b  c
# 1 50 30 30
# 2 40 10 20

df %>% filter(b+c<=a)
#   a  b  c
# 1 40 10 20
```